# Drupal 6 - change Author of a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, author

Is there an easy way to change the author of a node to another user? I can't seem to find it. I found a workaround, which was to setup an "action" to change the author of a node to a specific user, and then temporarily setup a "trigger" so that whenever i update a node, it should run that action. It works, but is ugly. I suppose I could also attack the db directly, but these both seem like rather inelegant solutions.

I appreciate this shouldn't be that common an requirement. This is what happened: I setup the site, including place-holder content, which the publisher users then populated with real content. This was clearly not the right way to go about it, but it's the situation I find myself in...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you simply edit the node, expand the Authoring Information section near the bottom of the page, and change the Author name.

You can also change the Authored on date too.

If you need to change the Authoring information of lots of pages, I'd recommend [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Changing the Author is one of the options.

Comment: this is embarrassing - i had installed the "node form columns" module, to hide "un-needed" options from the edit node page, and had hid the authoring information options...

Answer (score 3):

> Can't you simply edit the node, expand the Authoring Information section near the bottom of the page, and change the Author name.

It should be noted that in order to change these the administer nodes permission must be set for that account.  If this is undesired (and in production environments, it is), you can use the Rules module or use the nodeapi hooks to change the desired fields.

Comment: But also know that Administer Nodes gives a LOT of power to someone. Use with caution.

Comment: @Kevin: that's exactly my point.  Giving administer nodes to an account is undesirable.